# How to find and replace MAC address

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file which has a data-

```
a AA:22:CC:44:DD:66 bbc aa:44:55:77:dd:rr axa
AA:22:CC:44:DD:66 sds 77:dd:rr:aa:44:55 dd 00:3a:7d:52:16:01 dd
```

My requirement is to find all the MAC addresses and replace it with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

So my final output should be-

```
a XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX bbc XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX axa
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX sds XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX dd XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX dd
```

I have tried below, but it doesn't work fully

```
sed -r 's/(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})(.*)/\1\XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Remove all `(.*)` and `\1` and `\3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/([0-9a-eA-E]{2}:){5}[0-9a-eA-E]{2}/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/g' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply using `-E` option of `sed` which enables ERE for regex. Then using `s`(substitution option) to substitute `([0-9a-eA-E]{2}:){5}` digits, alphabets(small OR capital letters) 2  in number followed by a colon, then this combination should be there 5 times`{5}` and then again matching alphabets(small, capital letters) and digits 2 occurrences if match is found of this regex substitute them with `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. using `g` option to globally substitute all matched/found matched ones with new value.

Answer (score 2):

Since the pattern of a MAC is rather unique, you could make it short as:

```
sed -e 's/..:..:..:..:..:../XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/g'
```

This however might accidentally change other strings that could match this pattern. If you have to be 100% certain, then use the [solution of RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937985/8344060)